# passing a session variable in link created by for loop C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I have a page reading an api thats giving a list of ID's.
I then want that to create a link that then sends that ID to another API to get that individual object.
I've got the pages working manually but now trying to send the data between them is the issue.

My current code is this

```
@{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.records.Count; i++)
    {
        string currID = Model.records[i].ID;
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(Model.records[i].ID, "Game", "Home", Session["game"] = currID)</td>
        <td>@Model.records[i].GameName</td>
        <td>@Model.records[i].Player1</td>
        <td>@Model.records[i].Player2</td>
        <td></td><br />
    }    
}
```

What this does, And I understand Why, is pass the final record's ID to the api, and always gives me that result, as i is the final value at that point. 
how can I tell the link that it needs to keep it's iteration of i and pass that value?

Comment: you need to add the value of `i` to the link....

Comment: instead of Session["game"], just use a variable say Id and in your controller function use the variable id

Comment: @KarthikGanesan The reason I'm using a session variable is it's passing it to the next page, the best way I found to do that previously was storing a session variable.

Comment: try copying the value of i to a 'temp' int variable that is created inside the for loop. and then use that 'temp' variable in your method

Comment: What is the issue ? What is your expected behavior  ? What is the expected href value of the link ? What are you seeing now ?

Comment: How does the `Game` action method signature looks like ?

Comment: @GingerChris86 if you want to pass value to another page use Temp Variable

Answer (score 0):

With this expression,

```
Session["game"] = currID
```

You are actually updating the Session item value within the loop for each iteration with the current value of currID.

If you want to send the Session item value as querysting/route values, you may use the overload which takes 5 params. The fourth parameter is an anonymous object where you will specify the key and values, these key and values will be used to generate the URL.

For example, the below code will add the `gameId` querystring item and it's value will be the value stored in `Session["game"]`

```
@{
    var game = Session["game"]; 
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.records.Count; i++)
    {
        string currID = Model.records[i].ID;
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(Model.records[i].ID, "Game", "Home",
                                    new { gameId = game }, null)</td>
        <td>@Model.records[i].GameName</td>

    }    
}
```

Assuming your `Game` action method has a parameter with name `gameId`

```
public ActionResult Game(string gameId)
{
   // to do : Return something
}
```

If you want to send the `currID` as well, pass that too

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.records[i].ID, "Game", "Home",
                                        new { gameId = game, currId = currID }, null)
```

The fifth parameter( where I passed `null`) is for `htmlAttributes` which will be used to add other HTML attributes to the element rendered by this helper (Ex : If you want to add a CSS classs etc)